# Retaining a Signal or SignalProducer?

Tags: swift, reactive-cocoa

Is it my responsibility to maintain a reference to a `Signal` or a `SignalProducer`, e.g., using an instance variable?

In other words, will they automatically disappear and stop sending events when they get deallocated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FYI, not necessary, the `Signal` will be disposed and stop forwarding events.

`Signal`is a class type, if no one have a reference to it, it should be deinit. 
However, `Signal` implementation introduces a tricky way to retain itself, see `state` property, so that there exists some memory leaks in temporary. As seen in source code, if there have some observers subscribe on the `Signal`, it's `state` does retain it in turn until all observers unsubscribed or the `Signal` received **completed/error/interrupted** event.

Here some marked code snippets.

```
// definition of SignalState
private struct SignalState<Value, Error: Swift.Error> {
    var observers: Bag<Signal<Value, Error>.Observer> = Bag()
    var retainedSignal: Signal<Value, Error>?  // here is the key
}

public func observe(_ observer: Observer) -> Disposable? {
    var token: RemovalToken?
    state.modify {
        $0?.retainedSignal = self  // retain self when one observer on
        token = $0?.observers.insert(observer)
    }

    if let token = token {
        return ActionDisposable { [weak self] in
            if let strongSelf = self {
                strongSelf.state.modify { state in
                    state?.observers.remove(using: token)
                    if state?.observers.isEmpty ?? false {
                        // break retain cycle when disposed
                        state!.retainedSignal = nil  
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        observer.sendInterrupted()
        return nil
    }
}
```

How about `SignalProducer`?
It is really intuitive, `SignalProducer` is just `struct` type, and you should not consider its lifetime.